# Is using j_username and j_password as input field names a security risk

Tags: ssl, https, spring-security

One of my colleagues said that using the spring default login input params are a security risk. I did not ask him why. I am not convinced since an https connection would be encrypting the params when they are posted. Some clarification would help. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Without some explanation of why he thought there might be a risk it's hard to say.

The only (very minor) concern might be that someone might see them and be able to guess that you are using Spring Security. But that isn't inherently a risk in itself. Standard Java EE servlet security also uses `j_username` and `j_password` as the login parameters.

In any case, you can change the names in the configuration, and also the URL which the form submits to. You could also [change the session cookie name](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Session_cookie_configuration) to make it less obvious that you are even using a Java application. Of course if your app has `.jsp` URLs and dumps stacktraces back to the user when something goes wrong, none of this will matter.

I would ask your colleague to explain himself and provide some evidence for his assertion and why he thinks it's an issue. Changing the parameters is a good idea, but it's unlikely to be a major risk if you don't.

Comment: Yes the username pwd parameter names can be changed, but without a valid reason we should not. He was talking about sniffing the username and password. Anyway I will ask for an explanation from him.

Comment: Sniffing the username and password obviously has nothing to do with the parameter names. If you're using HTTPS then the information is protected. If you aren't, then the values can be sniffed no matter what the parameter names are.